# Realm Write Transaction without Notifying Any Observers in SwiftUI App

Tags: realm

I have certain writes I want to do on my Realm database without notifying any of the observers throughout my SwiftUI app. The reason is that I'm syncing my Realm database to CloudKit, and when CloudKit responds that the records were updated successfully, I set the `modified` property of the Realm objects to match the server. I don't want notifications to fire from that because it's a change the user already made in the UI and the sync round-trip shouldn't interrupt the UI.

Since my observers are sprinkled throughout various `ObservableObject`s in my app, I consolidate all the tokens on a singleton that I initialize when my app first starts up.

```
class RealmSetup{
  static let shared = RealmSetup()
  
  var tokenAlpha: NotificationToken? = nil
  var tokenBravo: NotificationToken? = nil
}
```

Then they get set elsewhere like this:

```
class AlphaModel: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = AlphModel()

  init(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    RealmSetup.shared.tokenAlpha = realm.objects(Alpha.self).observe { [weak self] _ in
      self?.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }
}
```

...and similarly:

```
class BravoModel: ObservableObject{
  static let shared = BravoModel()

  init(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    RealmSetup.shared.tokenBravo = realm.objects(Bravo.self).observe { [weak self] _ in
      self?.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the essence of my write:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
realm.beginWrite()

//Do a bunch of record changes...

//Find the non-nil notification tokens and try not to notify them
var tokensReady = [NotificationToken]()

for token in [RealmSetup.shared.tokenAlpha, RealmSetup.shared.tokenBravo]{
  if let ready = token{
    tokensReady.append(ready)
  }
}

try! realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: tokensReady)
```

The problem I'm having is that when the sync finishes, and I attempt to commit the write, I get a crash:

> *Incorrect Realm: only notifications for the Realm being modified can be skipped.*

So obviously the tokens aren't on the same realm as the write. As far as I can tell, my `ObservableObject`s are on the main thread, but I *still* get this crash if I wrap my write code in `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`.

I'm not an expert when it comes to threading, so I'm a bit confused. How can I ensure all this stuff happens on the same thread? Or is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Realm has the ability to write data without notifying the observers. See [write(withoutNotifying:_:)](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V5write16withoutNotifying_xSaySo20RLMNotificationTokenCG_xyKXEtKlF). I am curious why two separate databases? Realm and iCloud (CloudKit), when Realm can handle all of it? Would you mind sharing the use case?

Comment: Yeah, I mention the `withoutNotifying` option in my question and explained a related crash. I use CloudKit because I'm already familiar with it, it's free, it's stable, and the APIs require no authentication in my apps. I'm nervous about using MongoDB Realm sync due to the potential cost, and being overly dependent on a single vendor (I've been burned by that in the past).

Comment: I see. Well, rest assured Realm can handle the entire thing if you want to focus on one solution. I mentioned the withoutNotifying as it does work - we use it all the time. The code generally looks ok - although there may be a an issue with ObservableObject vs ObservedRealmObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store your server status in a separate object and create a `LinkingObjects` property:

```
class Something: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var someValue: String = ""

    let status = LinkingObjects<SomethingServerStatus>(
        fromType: SomethingServerStatus.self,
        property: "object"
    )

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }

    // ...
}


class SomethingServerStatus: Object {
    @objc dynamic var object: Something? = nil
    @objc dynamic var modified: Bool = false

    // ...
}
```

Make sure you link the server status to the object like this:

```
let objects = [
    Something(name: "zero"),
    Something(name: "one"),
    Something(name: "two"),
]
.map {
    SomethingServerStatus(object: $0)
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(objects)
}
```

Observe as usual:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.objects = realm.objects(Something.self)
    notificationToken = self.objects.observe { change in
        switch change {
        case .update(_, _, _, let modifications):
            // do something ...
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

When you need to update the server status just fetch and modify. This will not trigger a notification for any listeners:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.objects(SomethingServerStatus.self)
            .filter("object.name == %@", someName)
            .first?
            .modified
            .toggle()
    }
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you! I think it can be even simpler and still have the intended effect of not getting spurious notifications. I'll post another answer to show what I mean, but I'll mark yours as accepted since the idea is great.

Answer (score 0):

Spurred by @Rob's answer, I thought of just using a slightly simpler object relationship. Using his example, I can just do this:

```
//Example of a synced object class
class Something: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var someValue: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var status: Status

  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "name"
  }
}

//Sync status class
class Status: Object {
  @objc dynamic var modified = false
}
```

Then when my sync roundtrip finishes, I can just update the related object:

```
something.status.modified = Date()
```

...and the `Something` object's notifications will not fire because the change is on a related object. Thanks, Rob!

Comment: Are you sure that a change to the status will not result in a notification on Something? I think that it will.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't because I have other relationships and I have to find ways to arbitrarily change related objects in order to fire a change for their parent. But I could be wrong.

Comment: After trying this out, I'm finding that a downside is having to essentially double the number of objects in my Realm database in order to keep track of their modified and change states. I need a `Status` object for every regular object that gets synced. 

Comment: This solution will definitely trigger a notification on the parent object. That's one way that Realm differs from Core Data. Regarding doubling the objects in realm, I don't see how that is a problem. I can, however, think of a way to reduce the number of classes by implementing a single Status class rather than a separate Status class for each Class that you need to sync.